# Set zathura as a default viewer while using latexmk

Tags: latexmk

$ latexmk -pvc

When I use the above command, it open using XDvi. How to set zathura as a default viewer while using latexmk?

Answer (score 0):

In macOs/Linux add:

```
$pdf_previewer = 'zathura';
$pdf_update_method = 2
```

to `.conf/latexmk/latexmkrc` and

```
set filemonitor "signal"
```

to `.config/zathura/zathurarc`.